# OAuth2 Via GitHub Api - Refresh Token missing

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, github-oauth, oauth-refresh-token

I am using .NET 6 - `AddOAuth()` method to configure the authorization code flow. After the authentication via token endpoint, I received access token but refresh token is missing.

As per Github's article, to enable refresh token we have to use 'opt-in' feature - https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-04-30-expiring-user-to-server-access-tokens-for-github-apps/
But if we follow the article this option is not present under 'Developer Settings -> OAuth Apps -> App Name '.

I also tried `offline_access` scope but still didn't got any access token.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a feature for 'GitHub OAuth.
It only works, as an optional feature, with the newer 'GitHub Apps'
The naming convention they use is a bit confusing, I know.